# how to build a container kind of thing for executing my jobs

Tags: java

I want to develop a framework(eg automation) which people can use.The idea is i build a container kind of thing (eg tomcat but not exactly like a webserver).The container will have one xml file which will hold the enties of classes that are to be executed. (eg like web.xml of tomcat)

for eg xml (run.xml) can be like follows

```
<job>jobNameXyz</job>
<class>com.pkg.jobXyz <class>
```

Each of the xml job class should extedn MyBaseClass  like how servlet extends HttpServlet and override
specified method doJob

```
public class MyClass extends Job{

  public String doJob(){
   //do some thing
  }

}
```

When i place Myclass inside my continner and trigger container the jobmust run and the method doJob
How can this be done?Any one can enter deploy his jobs by putting his class file in our dir and then editing run.xml
How can this be done?Any guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container should parse the XML file, extract a list of class names, call `Class.forName` for all the class names, to get a list of [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) objects. Then use `Class.newInstance` to call the default constructor of each of the class, cast the created objects to `Job`, and call their `doJob` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would use (and have been using) ANT for this purpose.

EDIT:

The couple of techniques that I have used are:

1. Using ANT [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task
2. Using customized ANT [task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html).

Whichever technique you use, the idea is to call ANT to execute the build file. This can be invoked via invoking ANT process externally (using Runtime.exec java ant for instance) or invoking the build file [programmatically](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html).

Comment: van u tell me how can we use ANT HERE?

Comment: See the edited explanation. I will try to locate the actual example from my old archives and will update here.